# Были ли переданные данные на сервер?

Tags: сервер, данные

Такая ситуация - на сайте я хотела оформить заказ, аккаунта не создавала, хотела заказать как гость поэтому отметила галочку где стоял этот пункт "Заказать как гость", заполнила форму с данными (имя, фамилия, адрес, дата рождения), нажала "Далее", дальше был способ выбора оплата и кнопка "Далее", дальше я не нажала эту кнопку, вернулась назад, удалила все с корзины. В этом случае мои данные, которые я заполнял на первой страницы были отправлены на сервер или нет? Сайт оказался мошенническим, поэтому и волнует этот вопрос. На почту ничего не приходило.

Comment: Это известно только разработчику сайта. Отправляться может что угодно даже вообще без нажатий

Answer (score 1):

Мошеннические сайты устроены так, что всеми силами стремятся заполучить все данные, в то числе айпи адрес, версию браузера, ОС, возможно считывало нажатия напрямую, возможно нет , не зная адреса сайта никто и не скажет насчёт механизма передачи данных

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно обезопасить себя от этого в будущем? Я установила антивирус Касперский и подключила функцию Интернет-защита. Этого достаточно или нет? Извините, не сильна в этом.

Comment: @Аноним антивирус никак не поможет, он не может знать, является ли незнакомый ему сайт мошенническим или нет

Comment: включить здравый мышление и не гоняться за очень низкими ценами

Answer (score 0):

Всё зависит от того, как этот сайт написан. Если мошенникам не нужны ваши данные, а только номер карты и CVV/CVC, то нет, данные не были отправлены, если мошенникам для чего-то нужны ваши данные, то были отправлены.

P.S. чтобы купить тапочки нужно заполнить день рождения, класс!